# Bootstrap Popover in Sidebar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popover

I would like to use Bootstrap's popover feature in such a way that the window opens up in a sidebar instead of adjacent to the trigger button/text, but I can't figure out how that might work.  I tried giving the sidebar an id, and including the attribute data-viewport="#sidebar" but that doesn't seem to work.
I'm a teacher trying to do something for my class, not a programmer or anything, so any help would be greatly appreciated.
Here's a mockup of what I'm looking for: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBp5c.jpg

Here's what I have:

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div id="sidebar">
                Sidebar where the popup window should appear.
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-8">

            <p>This is the main content where the <span class="pop"
            data-content="Popover Content" data-html="true" data-toggle=
            "popover" data-trigger="hover" tabindex="0" title=
            "Title">trigger text</span> would be.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a rough example of what I think you are trying to accomplish.

JSFiddle: [Example Code](http://jsfiddle.net/jfielaidof/4znf2q14/1/)

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div id="sidebar">
            Sidebar where the popup window should appear.

            <span data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">Sidebar where the popup window should appear.</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-8">
This is the main content where the
        <a id="btn">trigger text</a>
        would be.
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$(function () {
    $("#btn").on("click", function(){
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover("toggle")
    });
});
```

Comment: It seems like that's getting closer, but not quite what I had in mind.  This wouldn't work for multiple popovers, right?  I added an image to the original post to provide a better sense of what I'm after.

Comment: Are you set on using the bootstrap popover for this? A custom function could handle this better I think.

Comment: No, I'm not set on using the popover at all.  I liked the way it brings up the annotation on a rollover, but just wanted to position the annotation differently.  If I can achieve that another way I'd love any pointers.

Comment: I updated the "Example Code" in my answer. You can add your own styling to this to customize the look and feel.

Comment: That's fantastic!  Thanks Clayton, I really appreciate it.  I'll play around with this.

Comment: Glad to help! If this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see: <http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work> for more information